# Unable to install postgresql-client client on AWS Cloud Shell

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudshell

I'm trying to install postgresql client from AWS Cloud shell, however getting below error:

```
Preparing your terminal...
Failed to open session : Timed out while opening the session
Trying to open session (Retrying. Attempt #1)
Connection is lost. Please refresh the browser to re-establish the connection.
[cloudshell-user@ip$ Try these commands to get started:
aws help  or  aws <command> help  or  aws <command> --cli-auto-prompt
[cloudshell-user@ip$ sudo apt install postgresql-client
sudo: apt: command not found
[cloudshell-user@ip$
```

I'm using the below command to install the postgresql client.

**sudo apt install postgresql-client.**

is there any way we could connect AWS RDS PostgreSQL from AWS Cloud Shell ? Like in GCP Cloud Shell ? When i try to connect from GCP Cloud shell, it allows me without any issues but the problem persists in the AWS cloud shell.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried refresh the browser as shown in the error? Besides, if your postgres is in the private subnet, cloud shell cannot access it. Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/jp/cloudshell/faqs/

Comment: Yes, I refreshed it. If psql client is not there by default then I'm looking for a way to install it on cloud shell

Answer (score 6):

cloudshell runs on Amazon Linux 2, which is based on centos or redhat enterprise linux.  It is not a debian-based system, so you will not find `apt` and friends.

You could try installing with `yum`, but you are probably best-off with the amazon-specific tooling:

```
sudo amazon-linux-extras install postgresql14
```

currently versions 11, 12, 13, and 14 are available

Comment: how do I start the service?